# How to Restrict xpath using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to restrict some xpath using `Link Extractor` but they gave me these error `you have  multiple values for argument` kindly give me some suggestion what mistake I am doing

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http imporrt Request
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import time
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class BarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bar'
    start_urls=["https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/?mode=geo#BrowseByState"]

   
    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//table[@class="categories"]//tr//td//a[@class="category"]//@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//table[@class="categories"]//tr//td[1]//a[@class="category"]//@href'))))
            yield Request(url ,rules,callback='base_url')

    def base_url(self,response):
        links = response.xpath('//table[@class="listings"]//a//@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            b_link = response.urljoin(link)
            yield{
                'url':b_link,
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your spider.

1. A `Rule` object is useless unless it is an attribute of a `crawlspider`.  If you simply want to use a LinkExtractor, then you can do so without wrapping it in a  Rule object.
2. `LinkExtractor`s extract links from selectors so you should include the `@href` at the end of your `restrict_xpaths` selector list.
3. This is the cause for the error you are receiving:  A Request objects expects only 1 positional argument, which is the url.  If it receives a second positional argument then is assumes that the value is the callback.  However in your example you have the url as the first parameter, something else as the second parameter and the callback is keyword argument, so it throws an error as having received multiple values for the callback parameter.  Also Request objects don't accept `Rule` objects as parameter.

What you can do to address these issues is instantiate a LinkExtractor directly, remove the `@href` part of your xpath, and then iterate the extracted links and yield a Request for each link extracted individually.

For example:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for link in LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=[
            '//table[@class="categories"]//tr//td[1]//a[@class="category"]'
        ]).extract_links(response):
            url = response.urljoin(link.url)
            yield Request(url,callback=self.base_url)
```

Comment: `for link in LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=['//table[@class="categories"]//tr//td[1]//a[@class="category"]']):
TypeError: 'LxmlLinkExtractor' object is not iterable`

Comment: it give me these error now

Comment: `raise TypeError("Cannot mix str and non-str arguments")
TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments`

Comment: again give  error

Comment: thanks it will not eleminate the first_url ............

Comment: I want they will eleminate first href

Comment: @AmenAziz  I think you have a misunderstanding of what restrict_xpaths does... it is used to isolate the links that you want to scrape not the links that you don't want to scrape.  If you want to know how to exclude certain xpaths using a link extractor then I suggest you open up another question, since this question has been answered.

Comment: sure I open other question you answer that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76638466/how-to-exclude-certain-xpaths-using-a-link-extractor