# how to exclude certain xpaths using a link extractor

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to know how I can exclude certain xpaths using link extractor. Please recommend any solution, for example: I want to exclude `first href` then how will I do using link extractor

```py
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.http import Request
    from selenium import webdriver
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
    import time
    from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    
    class BarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'bar'
        start_urls=["https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/?mode=geo#BrowseByState"]
    
       
        def parse(self, response):
            for link in LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=[
                '//table[@class="categories"]//tr//td[1]//a[@class="category"]'
            ]).extract_links(response):
                url = response.urljoin(link.url)
                yield{
                    "url":url,
                }
```